# How to pair countries with almost same names in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help how to pair little bit different names of countries. Problem is that I have two datasets from different sources. In first sheet names of countries are based on ISO names and shortcuts, but in second sheet names are not based on ISO names.

Sheet1:
[image]

Sheet2:
[image]

I tried use VLOOKUP function to pair official iso name with name from Sheet2,  but result of *United States* was *United Kingdom*

Have you got any thoughts how to avoid replacing problem names?

Thank you!

Comment: Add the `Code`  column to Sheet2. Make sure it corresponds.

Comment: @skutik It is nearly impossible if there are several variations. Formula or VBA approach may not really be able to give reliable results every time.

Comment: There are fuzzy lookups available, but inclined to agree with Shrivallabha Redij unless you can come up with a list of exceptions.

Comment: I think it will be easier to manually add shortcuts where names are different, anyway thanks a lot, all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a mapping table where you map the sheet1 country to the sheet2 country, then your lookup will have a nested vlookup to get the corresponding country in sheet2

```
=vlookup(vlookup(sheet1country,yourmappingtable,2,0),sheet2data,yourcolumn,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an approximative solution which would solve a major part of your table in VBA as below:

[image]

My Code is checking if it can find the string in the second Sheet and then enter the respective results in Sheet 1 below Metric 3. 
So in A2 it tries with:
1 United States of America
2 United States of Americ
3 United States of Ameri
...
13 United States (which would be the match)
the issue is that if you have a Country like "United Kingdom" which is different in the other list like "U.K", the result given would be the one of United States of America.

Nevertheless it takes out some manual work.

```
Sub Find_Countries()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To LastRow
Dim ra As Range
Dim a As Integer
a = Len(Range("A" & i))

Do
Set ra = Sheets(2).Cells.Find(What:=Left(Sheets(1).Range("A" & i), a), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

a = a - 1
Loop Until Not ra Is Nothing

Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value = ra.Offset(0, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```