# Matching elements of a column with other column in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I have two columns named 'Code' and 'Name' for example in a sheet named **Sheet1**

[image: Spreadsheet]

What I want to do is that each cell of 'Code' should be compared with every cell of 'Name' and then if some parts in sequence match then a separated column called 'Match' (as above) should display 'yes' or 'no' besides the column 'Code'. For example, first 'Wreakhavoc' in 'Code' column is checked with the 'Name' column then it can be seen that Wreakhavoc and 'Reak' have match (some parts of both words match in sequence) and then the column 'Match' display a yes as there is some match in sequence.

Comment: Is the column with "Reak", always smaller than the one with "Wreakhavoc"?

Comment: Yes , you are right

Comment: Then you can use something like the code from my answer there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456733/how-to-pair-countries-with-almost-same-names-in-excel/47668188#47668188
If so upvote pls :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range

    With Range("A3", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In Range("E3", Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
            Set f = .Find(what:=cell.Value2, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then Cells(f.Row, 3).Value2 = "yes"
        Next
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Offset(, 2)) > 0 Then .Offset(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "No"
    End With
End Sub
```

where I assumed that *codes* are in column A (column index=1), *matches* in column C (column index=3) and *names* in column E (column index=5).

Otherwise change column names and indexes as per your needs.